# Filtering second statement in UNION to prevent duplicate results

Tags: sql-server, select, union

I have gone around and around and can't quite figure out how to resolve this.  I have 2 tables.  One contains a maximum of 1 record per employee/customer/week listing the estimated number of hours they will work for that week.  This is the table below listed as "ForecastedActivities".  Another table lists billable activities.  It is possible for a given employee to have multiple records for billable activities for a given customer in a week.  These are listed in the table "BillableActivities".

I am attempting to create a select statement that would return a summary of all this information, as shown in the "Desired Output" table below, however with some additional aggregation and filter.  The output should have the forecasted hours,as a sum of all billable hours where approval = 1 as "Hours to Bill", and a sum of all billable hours where approval = 0 as "Planned Hours".

I suspect there is a more direct way than what I have done, but I have gotten VERY close.  The issue I am stuck on is that there are times when in a given week an employee will have forecasted hours but no billable hours, or vice versa.  To help with this I created a Union, but I know that this particular union will not work as intended because if the Resource exists in the forecasted activities at all for that week, even if for another customer, it will be excluded from the second statement.  I have tried going about this SEVERAL different ways, and I always run into some sort of roadblock.  I am okay with rewritting the statement in a totally different way if necessary.  I've tried using full outer joins, using an employee table as the basis and building off of that, nested select statements, etc, but always run into some sort of issue.

**BillableActivities**

```
customer                        resource        WeekNum  BillableHours  Approval
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee C      35       2              0
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee A      35       1              0
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee B      35       2              1
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee A      35       16             0
```

**ForecastedActivities**

```
Customer                        Resource        ActivityName EstHours WeekNum
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee A      Test         4        35
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee B      Publish      2        35
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee A      Build        3        35
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee B      Rework       3        35
```

**Desired Output**

```
Customer                        Resource    Wk 1 Forecast   Wk 1 Planned    Wk 1 To Bill
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee A  3               0               0
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee B  6               0               0
A. Datum Corporation (sample)   Employee C  0               2               2
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee A  2               0               2
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee B  7               0               0
B. Trippin Corporation (sample) Employee D  8               0               0
```

**Current Query** - note that this filters to the current week

```
select a.Customer,a.Resource,  
    sum(a.EstHours) as [Week 1 Forecast], 
    ISNULL(sum(c.billablehours),0) as [Week 1 Planned],
    ISNULL(sum(b.BillableHours),0) as [Week 1 To Bill],
    CAST(MAX(CAST(a.Onsite as INT)) as bit) as Onsite1
    from ForecastedActivities a
    left join BillableActivities b  on (a.Customer = b.Customer) and (a.Resource = b.Resource) and (a.WeekNum = b.WeekNum) and b.Approval = 1
    left join BillableActivities c  on (a.Customer = c.Customer) and (a.Resource = c.Resource) and (a.WeekNum = c.WeekNum) and b.Approval = 0
    where a.WeekNum = (DATEPART(week,getdate())) 
    group by a. Customer, a.Resource

    UNION

    select a.Customer,a.Resource, 
    0 as [Week 1 Forecast], 
    ISNULL(sum(c.billablehours),0) as [Week 1 Planned],
    ISNULL(sum(b.BillableHours),0) as [Week 1 To Bill]
    ,CAST(MAX(CAST(a.BillableHours as INT)) as bit) as Onsite1
    from BillableActivities a
    left join BillableActivities b  on (a.Customer = b.Customer) and (a.Resource = b.Resource) and (a.WeekNum = b.WeekNum) and b.Approval = 1
    left join BillableActivities c  on (a.Customer = c.Customer) and (a.Resource = c.Resource) and (a.WeekNum = c.WeekNum) and b.Approval = 0
    where a.WeekNum = (DATEPART(week,getdate())) and
    a.Resource not in (select Resource from ForecastedActivities where WeekNum = (DATEPART(week,getdate())))
    group by a.Resource, a. Customer
    order by Customer, Resource
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you could please set up a sql fiddle for this, it would be great.

Comment: sql fiddle is available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16012/1

Comment: In your Desired Output you have `Employee D`, but it is not in `BillableActivities` and it is not in `ForecastedActivities`. Where does it come from? In the SQL Fiddle you have a different set of sample data. It would help if you included in the fiddle a table with desired result based on the sample data included in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're attempting with the Onsite1 column, so I left that out.  However, here is a crack at the rest using a full outer join and selecting the non-null customer and resource.  I sum the approved/non-approved billable hours using a case statement:

```
select 
    ISNULL(f.Customer, b.customer) AS Customer,
    ISNULL(f.resource, b.resource) AS Resource,
    ISNULL(SUM(f.EstHours) + SUM(CASE WHEN b.approval=0 THEN b.billablehours ELSE 0 END),0) AS [Week 1 Forecast],
    ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN b.approval=1 THEN b.billablehours ELSE 0 END),0) as [Week 1 To Bill]
from ForecastedActivities f
    full outer join BillableActivities b
        on b.customer = f.customer
        and b.resource = f.resource
        and b.WeekNum = f.WeekNum 
where f.WeekNum = DATEPART(week,getdate())
group by ISNULL(f.Customer, b.customer), ISNULL(f.resource, b.resource)
order by ISNULL(f.Customer, b.customer), ISNULL(f.resource, b.resource)
```

Comment: You can ignore the onsite for right now.  The query appears to not be filtering down to a particular week, as I have in my query.  I failed to mention that in the intro.  The whole thing should be filtered to the current week number (32).

Comment: Also, not sure if you saw, but this is available in a sql fiddle @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16012/1

Comment: @LearningCurve **I failed to mention that in the intro.** Then edit the question instead of adding requirements via comments

Comment: **The query appears to not be filtering down to a particular week,** then simply add a filter for the week. morgb's query matches the expected result as given in the question see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0865f/1

Comment: @LearningCurve Ok - I edited the query to include a filter for the week number (based on the method demonstrated in your original query).

Answer (score 0):

- At first get a list of all `Customer,Resource,WeekNum` - this is `CTE_Main`.
- Then sum your hours three times: approved, not approved, forecast.
- Then left join sums to the main CTE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16012/35/0)

If you are interested only in a particular week, add a corresponding filter to all queries.

```
WITH
CTE_Main
AS
(
    SELECT
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
    FROM BillableActivities

    UNION

    SELECT
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
    FROM ForecastedActivities
)
,CTE_ToBill
AS
(
    SELECT
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
        ,SUM(BillableHours) AS SumToBill
    FROM BillableActivities
    WHERE Approval = 1
    GROUP BY
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
)
,CTE_Planned
AS
(
    SELECT
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
        ,SUM(BillableHours) AS SumPlanned
    FROM BillableActivities
    WHERE Approval = 0
    GROUP BY
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
)
,CTE_Forecast
AS
(
    SELECT
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
        ,SUM(EstHours) AS SumForecast
    FROM ForecastedActivities
    GROUP BY
        Customer
        ,Resource
        ,WeekNum
)
SELECT
    CTE_Main.Customer
    ,CTE_Main.Resource
    ,CTE_Main.WeekNum
    ,ISNULL(CTE_Forecast.SumForecast, 0) AS SumForecast
    ,ISNULL(CTE_Planned.SumPlanned, 0) AS SumPlanned
    ,ISNULL(CTE_ToBill.SumToBill, 0) AS SumToBill
FROM
    CTE_Main
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Forecast ON
        CTE_Forecast.Customer = CTE_Main.Customer AND
        CTE_Forecast.Resource = CTE_Main.Resource AND
        CTE_Forecast.WeekNum  = CTE_Main.WeekNum
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Planned ON
        CTE_Planned.Customer = CTE_Main.Customer AND
        CTE_Planned.Resource = CTE_Main.Resource AND
        CTE_Planned.WeekNum  = CTE_Main.WeekNum
    LEFT JOIN CTE_ToBill ON
        CTE_ToBill.Customer = CTE_Main.Customer AND
        CTE_ToBill.Resource = CTE_Main.Resource AND
        CTE_ToBill.WeekNum  = CTE_Main.WeekNum
;
```